# How to remove all escape characters from a string generated in java ,and java string replace() not working for `\`

Tags: java, html, string, freemarker

I have the following method in my `Java Spring MVC` web application that will store a `Freemarker Template` in a `Java String`.

```
private String processTemplate(Map<String, Object> variablesMap, String templateData)
    {
        Template template  = null;
        Writer out = new StringWriter();
        try 
        {
            template = new Template("userCollection", new StringReader(templateData), new Configuration());
            template.process(variablesMap, out);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (TemplateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
```

The String that is generated would be something like the following:

```
\r\n</li>\r\n<li class=\"col-md-4 col-sm-6\">\r\n<div class=\"feature-box\">\r\n<div class=\"user-details\">\r\n<h4 class=\"shorter\">\r\nDeveloper\r\n</h4>\r\n<p class=\"tall\">\r\nName : <strong>Leo Ralph</strong><br/>\r\nFamily Name : <strong>An quo impetus percipit efficiantur</strong><br/>\r\nNickname : <strong>An quo impetus percipit efficiantur</strong><br/>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</div>\r\n</li>
```

And what I actually  require is:

```
<li class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="feature-box">
<div class="user-details">
<h4 class="shorter">
Developer
</h4>
<p class="tall">
Name : <strong>Leo Ralph</strong><br/>
Family Name : <strong>An quo impetus percipit efficiantur</strong><br/>
Nickname : <strong>An quo impetus percipit efficiantur</strong><br/>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

Is there any way that I can do this in java.

As per the suggestions from the comments, I have tried the following:

```
collectionData = collectionData.replace("\r", "");
collectionData = collectionData.replace("\t", "");
collectionData = collectionData.replace("\n", "");
collectionData = collectionData.replace("\\", "");
```

But the `\` is still there. The other characters have gone now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `replace()` method from String class.

```
/* This will actually be stored as "Line 1\\r\\nLine 2\\r\\nLine 3" */
String example = "Line 1\\r\\nLine 2\\r\\nLine 3";
example = example.replace("\\r\\n", "\n");
System.out.println(example);
```

The following code will print out:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Comment: I don't want any of the escape characters in my string, all I want are the html elements

Comment: You can replace these string characters with anything you like, even an empty string "". I put the newline character "\n" to match your requirement.

Comment: everything works, I had to replace each special character with separate replace() method calls. But data.replace("\\", "") is not working for me, i need to remove the \ also